# Can someone explain this circuit to me? Is it a voltage level shifter?

Tags: circuit-design, uart, esp32

[image]

The UART_RX and UART_TX is coming from ESP32 connecting to another mU's UART Pins (LPC2131).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this circuit is a pair of level shifters.

When the voltage at the emitter of either Q1 or Q2 is 0 or near 0, current flows through the corresponding base resistor, and the base-emitter voltage is sufficient for the transistor to turn on. Collector current flows, causing a voltage drop across the corresponding collector resistor. The voltage at the collector is therefore low.

When the voltage at the emitter of either Q1 or Q2 rises, the base-emitter voltage falls. This causes the collector current to fall. This in turn means the voltage across the collector resistor falls, making the voltage at the collector rise.

It is slightly unusual, but it is perfectly valid for the base-emitter junction to be reverse biased. This occurs in Q1 when the emitter voltage is +5 V. The reason such a configuration is slightly unusual is that the reverse breakdown voltage of a base-emitter junction is often quite low, for example 5 V. However, in this particular circuit, when the emitter is 5 V and the base is 3.3 V, the base-emitter junction is only reverse biased by 5-3.3 = 1.7 V. So, operating in this mode, in this case, is fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your schematic the transistors are **common base** connected to increase the switching speed what high-speed UART really needs. Signal goes to emitter with this configuration, i.e the transistors are emitter driven/controlled.

On other hand with **common emitter** connection you are not able to reach such a speed even when you overdrive the bases. But controlling the transistors drains less current comparing to common base.

*Common base connection:*

[image]

The source of image: Wikipedia

The schematic above is almost the same as your circuit. The only difference is the base is held at 3v3 (not Gnd). The 3v3 determines the threshold when the transistor opens/closes (-0.7V of course)